# BeanUtil does not copy data between 2 objects

Tags: apache-commons, apache-commons-beanutils, jodd

In Jodd `BeanUtil` class does not have a method that will copy data from one object to another, i.e. in apache commons `BeanUtils` class there is a method `copyProperties` that will copy data from one object to another.

In Jodd we have to pass the name of the field and its value. If there are like 20+ fields do we have to do this manually for all the 20 fields or is there a better way of doing it using Jodd `BeanUtil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is such tool in Jodd - its just in different class: `BeanCopy` ([javadoc](http://jodd.org/api/jodd/bean/BeanCopy.html)). This class offers some more control over copy process, like including/exluding some properties and so on. It was too big to put all this functionality in the `BeanUtil` :)

Take a look at the [test sources](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/blob/master/jodd-bean/src/test/java/jodd/bean/BeanCopyTest.java), you will find many examples there. Here are some quick examples:

```
BeanCopy.beans(src, dest).copy();
BeanCopy.beans(src, dest).include("fooInteger", "fooLong").copy();
BeanCopy.beans(fooBean, dest).includeAs(FooBeanString.class).copy();
BeanCopy.beans(src, dest).declared(true).copy();
```

and so on.